# How to remove parent node in an XML if it has a child node with specific value in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need to remove a parent node from the XML document if it has a child node with a specific value.

For instance, I have my XML string as follows:

```xml
<Container>
    <Objects>
        <Object>
            <Id>1</Id>
        </Object>
        <Object>
            <Id>2</Id>
        </Object>
    </Objects>
</Container>
```

I'm parsing this as `XDocument`:

```cs
var container = XDocument.Parse(aboveXmlString);
```

Now I need to remove `<Object>` tag which has `<Id>` tag with value `1`. I can traverse elements using:

```cs
container.Element("Objects").Element("Object").Element("Id")
```

But If I add `.Remove()` to the above code it removes the `<Id>` from XML. How to access its parent and remove the parent `<Object>` element. I'm confused with this `XDocument` as I'm new to this.

After removing I need my `XML` as follows,

```xml
<Container>
    <Objects>
        <Object>
            <Id>2</Id>
        </Object>
    </Objects>
</Container>
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to get all child elements of `Objects` node and remove the element whose child `Id` value equals `"1"`

```cs
var objects = container.Root?.Element("Objects")?.Elements();
objects?.Where(o => o.Element("Id")?.Value == "1").Remove();
Console.WriteLine(container);
```

It'll print

```
<Container>
  <Objects>
    <Object>
      <Id>2</Id>
    </Object>
  </Objects>
</Container>
```

Don't forget to access a `Root` of `XDocument` instance, rather then instance itself

Comment: What's the difference between accessing using through `Root` and `Descendants`?

Comment: @fingers10 Have a look at this [Querying an XDocument vs. Querying an XElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/querying-an-xdocument-vs-querying-an-xelement) article for detailed information. In your particular sample it shouldn't be a difference

Comment: Thanks for the link and guidance. Respect Earned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Linq` to delete elements from `xml`, like the following code:

1 - To delete all `Object` that have `Id=1`:

```
XDocument container = XDocument.Parse(aboveXmlString);

container.Descendants("Object")
    .Where(x => x.Element("Id").Value == "1")
    .Remove();
```

2 - if you need to delete just the first item, that have `Id=1`:

```
container.Descendants("Object")
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Element("Id").Value == "1")
    ?.Remove();
```

I hope this help.